# Determine the conditions on a, b, and c so that the system has a solution? (Matrices)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Determine the values of a, b, and c so that the system has a solution:

x + 2y + 4z = a
2x + 3y - z = b
3x + y + 2z = c

Now, all I did was reduce the system to row-echelon form using gauss elimination as such:

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1 & 2 & 4 & (a) \\
        2 & 3 & -1 & (b) \\
        3 & 1 & 2 & (c) \\
    \end{array}
\right] $$

~

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1 & 2 & 4 & (a) \\
        0 & -1 & -9 & (b - 2a) \\
        0 & -5 & -10 & (c - 3a) \\
    \end{array}
\right] $$

~

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1 & 2 & 4 & (a) \\
        0 & -1 & -9 & (b - 2a) \\
        0 & 0 & 35 & (c +7a -5b) \\
    \end{array}
\right] $$

so the last equation of the system becomes 35 = c + 7a - 5b but from here I'm not sure how to choose the values of a, b, and c for the system to have a solution.

Comment: You divide the last row by $35$. You can further reduce after that to get the identity on the LHS. This results in this system having infinite solutions - so you have three free variables to choose $a, b, c$.

Comment: @Amzoti I don't follow

Comment: If you divide the last row by $35$, you have a $1$ in location $a_{33}$. Now, you can use that to zero out the 3rd column in the other two rows. Then you can get rid of the 2. Now, you have $I$ on the LHS. Clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can further row reduce and end up with:

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1 & 0 & 0 & \dfrac{1}{5} (2 c-a) \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & \dfrac{1}{35} (7 a+10 b-9 c) \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & \dfrac{1}{35} (7 a-5 b+c) \\
    \end{array}
\right] $$

Now, notice that you have three free variables and they can be chosen any way you like for an infinite number of unique solutions.

Comment: This makes it clear. Thanks very much!